# Free involutions and equivariant maps

Tags: reference-request, transformation-groups

The following paper of Conner and Floyd does not include proofs of many theorems/ results.

'Fixed point free involution and equivariant maps , Bull. Amer. Math. Society vol 66, no. 6( 1960)'.
I would also like to know where were the proofs published. I am trying to find the source containing the details of the paper for past 3 years. I would be really grateful if some one helps me in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

MR0176478 (31 #750) 
Conner, P. E.; Floyd, E. E.
Differentiable periodic maps. 
Ergebnisse der Mathematik und ihrer Grenzgebiete, N. F., Band 33 Academic Press Inc., Publishers, New York; Springer-Verlag, Berlin-Göttingen-Heidelberg 1964 vii+148 pp. 
57.10 (55.36)